# Couldn't Light just have burned the page himself?

Tags: plot-explanation, death-note-2017

In [Death Note (2017)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1241317/), Mia writes in the book that Light's heart will stop at midnight so that she could obtain the book from him. When she received the book, she was going to burn his page so that he didn't die.

Since Light was the current owner, why couldn't he just burn the page himself? One would assume that only the person who wrote the name could burn it, but this wasn't explicitly mentioned as one of the rules. Additionally, if the book only has one owner at any given time, and only they could see and speak to Ryuk, how is it that anyone could use the book?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Light does in fact quote the rule about destroying a page -

> If **the person who writes a name** destroys its page prior to the death being carried out, the target will be spared.

This is why he had to specifically write that Mia would tear the page out.

As for who can write in it, Mia uses a page to kill people, so we *know* that you don't need to be the official owner to use it.

Comment: +1 Nice. Completely ignored this line. The movie was so terrible I just wanted it to end! xD

Comment: I too missed that.